# Datatype mismatch issue in a Parametrized insert query

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, parameters, types

I have this code to transfer records from one-table to the other

```
cmd2.CommandText = "select * from " + TableName;
                    reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader != null)
                    {

                        String s = "".PadLeft(reader.FieldCount - 1, 'X').Replace("X", "?,") + "?";
                        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("{0} into {1} values ({2})", insertorreplace, TableName, s);

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int i = 0;

                            for (i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(null,reader[i].ToString()); // data type issue
                            }
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
```

Probably because of the commented line I get data type issue. I want all things to be passed by string.

**Still looking for answers**

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying from one table to another, the best thing is to do it all in one query with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`.

To fix your code, just remove `.ToString()` from `reader[i]`.

Comment: Using a insert into select from statement I get malformed database error, as I have to attach a new SQLite database, and it turns out it doesn't work as supposed to.

Removing .ToString() doesn't help, as for example non-null columns needs to have empty value, and the provider sends null for it. SQLite doesn't force type, but I think the provider forces it.